# CSS refuses to display on my page. Directory Issue? WebPack?

Tags: javascript, html, css, intellij-idea, webpack

I'm sure its something simple but I've googled way too many different solutions to know where i went wrong now. 
I plan to make this a full site in good time but i am still fresh. Any help is appreciated. Here's the header and nav followed by css I've been tinkering with

```html
/*General Styles*/
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #007bff;

}
header nav #left{
  background: #0f6674;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding-top: 50px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #c82333;
}

header nav {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}
header ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header li{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
/*Positions Container*/
.container{
  position:relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

:

```html
<!doctype HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title> Artistic Audio & Visual D.C. </title>
  <meta name="description" content="Distributed Home Systems"/>
  <meta name = "author" content ="Elishua S. Brown"/>
  <meta name="authorURL" content="http://www.artavdc.com/index.html"/>

  <!--Mobile Specific-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--Internet Explorer-->
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'/>

  <!--Bootstrap-->
  <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <!-- Reset page styles & Add Custom Styles-->
  <link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="Reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="Homepage.js"> </script>


  <title> Artistic Audio/Visual | Welcome! </title>
</head>

  <body>

  <header>

  <!--Navigation Bar-->
    <!--Add Logo to SRC-->
  <img src= "src/img/Artav-logo-w.jpg" id="logo" alt="" />

    <div id= NavBarImg"></div>



      <nav>

        <ul id="left">

          <h1>You Imagine It, We Create It</h1>
          <li><a href="Artistic%20Home.html">Artistic Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Audio.html">Audio Installation</a></li>
      


        </ul>
        <ul id="right">
          <li><input type="search" id="navSearch" placeholder="Search"></li>

          <h2>Subscribe to Recieve Special Offers & Updates</h2>

          <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Company Name.."/>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email.."/>
            <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>


          </form>

          <!--Add link to Appointment Request Form-->
          <li><a href="">Request Appointment</a></li>



        </ul>

    </nav> <!--End Nav-->
```

To my knowledge, I've closed and used all tags properly. It must be something fairly simple, I'm not really sure.

Comment: I don't know actually what your problem, but according to provided files, i think it works well. if your `reset.css` removes all styles in other files put it top of your imports.

Comment: Are Styles.css and Reset.css in the same folder as your index.html file? Also, what do they look like?

Comment: Don't know what exactly are you suggesting. Where did you include the stylesheet? Is it `Styles.css`? Is the css inline? Did you use `<style>` tags for inline css? Can you show us a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr If OP could provide his example using snippets here, it would be even better ;)

Comment: C:\Users\elish\IdeaProjects\ArtisticAVDC\src\CSS\Styles.css
C:\Users\elish\IdeaProjects\ArtisticAVDC\src\CSS\Reset.css
C:\Users\elish\IdeaProjects\ArtisticAVDC\Artistic Home.html

These are the paths i've copied from intellij.

Comment: Prepend the path to your css directory, i.e., like `src/CSS/Reset.css`, `src/CSS/Styles.css` and so on... Is your bootstrap css getting applied? If not check it's path too... To first test, you can copy your css files to current directory and include them like in your question (already). Are the styles applied then?

Comment: Open developer tools on your browser and go to network tab. Then reload the page and from there you can see which resources fail to load. If you get a 404 for the resources, that definitely means either the path to the files you included is wrong or the path itself doesn't exist. Path and file names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `./Reset.css` when you want to include files that are in the same directory.

If your files are in another directory you should use `./css/Reset.css`.

Also be aware that your files should be named with uppercase if you want it to work.

Based on your paths that you have left in comments you should include them like this:

```
./src/CSS/Styles.css
```

Comment: Where is documented? Any citation? My websites are running on magic then... Neither my filenames start with uppercase nor do i use a `./` in path

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr URLs are case-sensitive so when you are including a css file basically you are callin an URL. In windows that won't be a problem even if the casing is wrong but most of linux servers yes. If you are using a linux server and your files are named lowercase and you are calling them uppercase then you will get a 404 error

Comment: Filenames are case sensitive, yes, but your answer nowhere suggests about case sensitivity... It rather suggests that the files should be named with uppercase letters for them to work, which is absolutely wrong. Moreover, ./ simply means from current directory. It works absolutely fine without ./ Unless you want to include a file that needs the server to look up in directory tree, which then needs ../, ../.. and so on.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr please read carefully what the question was. From his code he is trying to include Styles.css so what I said is that file should be uppercase because he is trying to include it as Styles.css not styles.css so my suggestion here is right. If you inlcude Styles.css then your file should be uppercase.

Comment: i doubt it was the capitals giving me the issue. I think my directories got copied so i'm going to add specific file paths and run webpack and let you know how it turns out. Thank you guys i know it was a very concise question

Comment: @ElishuaBrown you have problems with directories and you need to include them as I said in my updated answer.